# c++ how to blank out incorrect choice on 2nd chance of a quiz?

Tags: c++, arrays

im writing a quiz program. if the user is wrong the 1st time, he can choose to get a 2nd try, which i must display by blanking out his original choice, so instead of ABCD he only sees AB D or something. If you got an idea or can post a link id appreciate it . ive marked the problem area with //  below.

```
int player_try (string questions[][5], char answers[]  )
{
char user_guess;
int m = 0;
srand(time(NULL));
int x;
int choice;
int total = 1;
int score = 0;

for (m=0; m<6; m++)
     {

    x = (rand() % 7);
    cout << user_name << ": Here is question number " << m+1 << endl;
    cout << m+1 << ". " << questions[x][0]<< endl;
    cout << "A. " << questions[x][1]<< endl;
    cout << "B. " << questions[x][2]<< endl;
    cout << "C. " << questions[x][3]<< endl;
    cout << "D. " << questions[x][4]<< endl;
    cin >> user_guess;
    user_guess = toupper(user_guess);

    while (!(user_guess >= 'A' && user_guess <= 'D'))
            {
            cout << "Please choose a valid answer.";
            cin>> user_guess;
            user_guess = toupper(user_guess);
        }
    if (user_guess != answers[x])
            {
            cout <<"Wrong!" <<endl;
                cout << "Skip this question or try again?" << endl;
            cout << "If you are wrong again... game OVER! No points!" << endl;
                cout << "Press 1 to skip, press 2 to take a chance at greatness." << endl;
            cin  >> choice;
                if (choice == '1')
                {
                            cout << "we shall skip this question." << endl;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                 cout << "I applaud your bravery." << endl;
                 cout << user_name << ": Here is question number " << m+1 << endl;
                     cout << m+1 << ". " << questions[x][0]<< endl;
                     cout << "A. " << questions[x][1]<< endl;  // here is where im stuck
                     cout << "B. " << questions[x][2]<< endl;  // how do i blank out an incorrect choice?
                     cout << "C. " << questions[x][3]<< endl; //thanks
                     cout << "D. " << questions[x][4]<< endl;
                     cin >> user_guess;
                     user_guess = toupper(user_guess);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Chad.

If you want a simple way to handle it, store the answer given in a variable, then add some checks to see if this answer you are writing is the same as already answered, and skip it if they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like homework, so I will give you some hints instead of some code.

Copy the possible answers (`question[][1-4]`) into a temporary array of `std::string`.

Display the temporary array in place of (instead of) the possible answers.

After the user picks a guess, clear out the appropriate entry in the temporary array.

Comment: all i ask for is guidance. thanks for the help i got it now!